# Find a $\delta$ such that $\lvert \sqrt{x} - 1 \rvert<\varepsilon$ for all $x$ satisfying $0<\lvert x-1 \rvert <\delta$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Can we choose $\delta=\varepsilon$?

This is problem 3(vi) from Spivak's Calculus chapter 5. I think he's essentially asking to prove that $\lim_{x \to 1} \sqrt{x} =1$.

Spivak's proof (in the solution manual) considers the two cases $\varepsilon >1$ and $\varepsilon<1$, and arrives at $\delta=2\varepsilon-\varepsilon^2$ for $\varepsilon<1$.

But can't we just choose $\delta=\varepsilon$? as follows:

Since $x$ is real,

$\frac{1}{\sqrt x+1}\le1$

$\frac{\lvert x-1 \rvert}{\sqrt x+1}\le\lvert x-1 \rvert$

and so

$\lvert {\sqrt x-1} \rvert
=\lvert (\sqrt x-1) \cdot\frac{\sqrt x+1}{\sqrt x+1} \rvert
=\lvert \frac{x-1}{\sqrt x+1} \rvert
= \frac{\lvert x-1\rvert}{\sqrt x+1} 
\le \lvert x-1 \rvert
<\delta
=\varepsilon$

As required?

Comment: Spivak's solution manual proof, ad verbatim: If $\varepsilon>1$, let $\delta=1$. Then $\lvert x-1\rvert<\delta$ implies that $0<x<2$, so $0<\sqrt x<2$, so $\lvert \sqrt x-1 \rvert <1$. If $\varepsilon<1$, then $(1-\varepsilon)^2<x<(1+\varepsilon)^2$ implies that $\lvert \sqrt x -1 \rvert < \varepsilon$, so it suffices to choose $\delta$ so that $(1-\varepsilon)^2\le 1-\delta$ and $1+\delta\le (1+\varepsilon)^2$. Thus we can choose $\delta = 2\varepsilon-\varepsilon^2$.

Comment: I think that works, if you also restrict $\delta$ to be $< 1$. You're cleverly exploiting the fact that for positive numbers not equal to $1$, their square roots head towards $1$, regardless of which side of $1$ they lie on.

Comment: $\delta = \min(1,\varepsilon)$ keeps $x$ from being negative (and $\sqrt{x}$ from running into trouble).

Comment: "I think that works..." = I think *your* solution works. Spivak's works too.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, except that, when you wrote ${\sqrt x-1} \cdot\frac{\sqrt x+1}{\sqrt x+1}$, you should have written $\left({\sqrt x-1}\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt x+1}{\sqrt x+1}$.

Comment: Oops, will edit. Thanks!